# What is "Charlie &" in the gecos field on OpenBSD for root?

Tags: openbsd, history, passwd

[image]

**Question**: what is "Charlie &" for the root user? I didn't gave "Charlie &" for gecos field, I think I didn't gave any at all.

ps.: the "/sbin/nologin" doesn't matters, I just tested something

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535189/5132 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the default you get if you leave it out. It comes from Charlie (the) Root (user) and I've seen it show up as a name over the years in articles and papers. Don't know where it orignated but at least before 1995.

The `&` in the Gecos field is automatically replaced by `root`.

It is mentioned e.g in [Matt Bishops paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.7048&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (page 6). And it has its own  [wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Root_%28%E3%82%AA%E3%83%9A%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%29) article which says that it is a reference to the baseball player [Charlie Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Root)

Comment: My understanding is the `&` is replaced by the username of that entry, which is `root` in this case, but could be used in other entries.  Not that I've ever seen it used that way...

Comment: `&` is replaced by the username with its first letter capitalized. The `root` account's full name was indeed set to `Charlie Root` as a joke - perhaps Charlie Root was a household name in the United States at the time BSD was created.

Comment: There are other jokes in passwd. In NetBSD, there's `toor: Bourne-again Superuser` (if the `root` account doesn't work and you need a backup account - `Bourne` is a reference to Stephen Bourne who wrote the original `sh` shell, and a pun on _born-again_). NetBSD also has `daemon: The devil himself` for background programs.